# Material UI Accordion closing when interacting with components inside the Accordion, e.g Select Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React, and Material UI for my frontend at the moment. The data get's fetched from an API, from which I then render multiple Accordions. Inside the Accordion is two Select components and a Switch.

Upon making a change to any of the two Select components, or the Switch, the Accordion closes or collapses.

I've Googled and ChatGPT'd, all I could find is adding the code "event.stopPropogation()" to my handler functions for the Selects and my Switch.

However, the Accordion still closes or collapses even when adding this code.

I've used Context now to set the "expand" prop on the Accordion, but now I've lost the animations on the Accordion and the components inside.

Can anyone help me, please? I have no idea what else to do.

Please see my example handler function:

```
const handleDropChange = (index) => (event) => {
event.stopPropagation();
setOutputData((prevState) =>
  prevState.map((item, i) => {
    if (i === index) {
      return {
        ...item,
        drop: event.target.checked,
      };
    }
    return item;
  })
);
```

See the code below to see how I pass the function via props

```
<Grid item xs={3} sm={3} lg={9}>
        <Box width={"10%"}>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={props.drop}
                  onChange={props.onChangeDrop}
                />
              }
              label="Drop"
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
```

onChangeDrop is the function that I pass to the Accordion component to change the value of the Switch component.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75359304/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Ruben. My first time posting on Stackoverflow instead of just hunting for answers.

Comment: You should share where the function is being used as well

Comment: The function was originally used in the same file as the Accordion, but I have since split out the Accordion into it's own component, since it didn't work previously either. 

So now I am passing my function as a prop to the Accordion component.

Comment: You should share the Accordion component, the current code looks good we can't do to much with this

Comment: Seems I am unable to add the code to comments since there is a character limit. I'll add snippets to my original post just now.

Comment: Can you respond using the answer function, please? The comments seem very limited.